# How to handle MEMCACHED_SERVER_MARKED_DEAD?

Tags: memcached, libmemcache

I have a cluster of 10 memcaches, using consistent hashing. When the key passed to `memcached_get()` is searched on the unavailable server I get just `MEMCACHED_SERVER_MARKED_DEAD` response (return value).

I would expect the key should be redistributed to the next available server in this case and I should get `NOTFOUND` from the next `memcached_get()` call. However I'm still getting `MEMCACHED_SERVER_MARKED_DEAD` and so I'm unable to set a new value.

I discovered I can call `memcached_behavior_set(..., MEMCACHED_BEHAVIOR_DISTRIBUTION)`. This causes hash redistribution and it works as I wish then. However, I do not think it is a good approach. Is it?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I found the answer myself.

https://bugs.launchpad.net/libmemcached/+bug/777672

Applying the patch solved all my problems. Note, I wonder it has beed broken since 0.39 and nobody has cared.

Answer (score -1):

Generally you want to enable MEMCACHED_BEHAVIOR_DISTRIBUTION from the start if you are dealing with multiple memcached pools. So yes that solution will work.

If you are having further problems, take a look at MEMCACHED_BEHAVIOR_REMOVE_FAILED_SERVERS that will auto purge failed servers from pool after x number of failures.